# Unable to update a User Record in nodejs/mongodb

Tags: node.js, angular, mongodb, ionic3

I am trying to update a user model in mongodb from ionic 3 app but it isn't working 
all I get is

**Request Method: OPTIONS**

**Status Code: 204 No Content**

Client side code :

```
 return this.http.put(this.serveBaseUrl+'/user/update/'+params._id, params).pipe(map((res : any) => {

  console.log('here is',res)
   return res;
 }))
```

My server Side code is

```
router.put('/update/:userId',controller.update_a_userModel);

Controller

User.findOneAndUpdate({ _id: req.params.userId }, req.body, { new: true }, function (err, users) {
        if (err)
            res.send(req.params.userId);
    res.json(req.params.userId);
  });
```

and in response I get a null value and the User record remains the same.

Any Help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you just sending JSON to your backend. 
Try Below:

```
User.findOneAndUpdate({ _id: req.params.userId }, {$set:req.body}, { new: true }, function (err, users) {
        if (err)
            res.send(req.params.userId);
    res.json(req.params.userId);
  });
```